# Displaying variable data in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

I have looked at so many tutorials/examples (I've spent a LOT of time here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and I still can't figure out how to properly use a JTable to represent data (it's all strings) that changes at runtime. I do NOT want it to be modifiable by selecting rows/cells. The data is modified by my program at runtime (including the amount of rows) AFTER the table is initially created (it's created empty).

I tried an inner class

```
private class PairingsTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
 ...
 public void setValueAt(String value, int row, int col) {
  data[row][col] = value;
  fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
 }
 ...
}
```

and my JTable is instantiated as follows

```
JTable pairingsTable = new JTable(new PairingsTableModel());
```

And it uses the data I provide as instance variables for pairingsTableModel but pairingsTable.getModel() doesn't seem to return the pairingsTableModel (calling pairingsTable.getModel().setValueAt("Hello",0,0) does nothing and Eclipse thinks I'm not using setValueAt anywhere)

Comment: For better help sooner post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why are you creating a custom TableModel? The DefaultMethod implements all the method you appear to need, setValueAt(), addRow(...), removeRow(...) etc...

Comment: @Micromancer Does my answer solve your problem? Do you need any more information?

Answer (score 1):

You have not correctly **overridden** setValueAt(...), you've actually **overloaded** by using a parameter of String rather than Object...

This means that the following calls TableModel.setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) not your custom method setValueAt(String aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)

```
pairingsTable.getModel().setValueAt("Hello", 0, 0)
```

Change your setValueAt() to the following, and things should start worked as expected

```
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
    data[row][col] = (String)value;
    fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
}
```

Full MCVE

```
private static class PairingsTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private String[][] data = new String[][] { new String[] { "foo", "bar" } };
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        data[row][col] = (String)value;
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.length;
    }
    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 1;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return data[rowIndex][columnIndex];
    }
}
private static int clock;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    final PairingsTableModel model = new PairingsTableModel();
    JTable pairingsTable = new JTable(model);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(pairingsTable, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            pairingsTable.getModel().setValueAt("test" + clock++, 0, 0);
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
}
```

Comment: 1+,  Use @Override before a method you are trying to override. If you override the method signature incorrectly you will get a compiler error.